# How do I fix this weird shading problem?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

[image: issue demo]

This problem is present on about half of the entire model, on seemingly random faces. The problem only appears when viewing the material, not in normal solid shading. The problem appears in both EEVEE and Cycles (pic is from Eevee). I have checked the normals, and all normals are facing the same way.

Comment: maybe try a Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: @moonboots there were no custom split normals data to clear

Comment: enable the *face orientation* overlay and check if your normals are not poiting opposite directions in that area. Otherwise maybe post your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here so that we can check ourselves.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)